# How do you subtract two columns in a data frame IF they exist in the data frame?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame with values. I want to `mutate` the subtracted columns into new columns. Sometimes a column isn’t present so I want it to run and mutate for the columns that are present, if not, don’t fail, just do the rest of the columns. Almost like a `mutate if exists`

For example,

```
Df <- df %>% mutate(columnxdif = columnxbeg -columnxend, columnydif = columnybeg-columnyend)
```

If `columnxend` isn’t present, it will still run and return `columnydif` mutated as a new column on the df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always easier with sample data, but let's make a little example here that matches the description of your data:

```r
df <- data.frame(columnxbeg = 1:5, columnxend = 6:10,
                 columnybeg = 2:6, columnyend = 8:12)

df
#>   columnxbeg columnxend columnybeg columnyend
#> 1          1          6          2          8
#> 2          2          7          3          9
#> 3          3          8          4         10
#> 4          4          9          5         11
#> 5          5         10          6         12
```

To do this in a single pipeline, we need to find the columns that have the suffix "beg" and the columns with the suffix "end", ensure they are in the correct order, subtract them, and bind them onto the existing data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  bind_cols(((df %>%
    select(ends_with("beg")) %>%
    select(order(names(.)))) -
    (df %>%
    select(ends_with("end")) %>%
    select(order(names(.))))) %>%
    rename_with(~str_replace(.x, "beg", "diff")))
#>   columnxbeg columnxend columnybeg columnyend columnxdiff columnydiff
#> 1          1          6          2          8          -5          -6
#> 2          2          7          3          9          -5          -6
#> 3          3          8          4         10          -5          -6
#> 4          4          9          5         11          -5          -6
#> 5          5         10          6         12          -5          -6
```

This will work with any number of columns, as long as they have a consistent naming pattern.

<sup>Created on 2022-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>